# How does the unit testing for decorator pattern in c#?

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, nunit

How does the unit testing for decorator pattern in c#?

I use decorator pattern for design repository , for longing , CURD operations , Cashing. 
Then how do I wright unit testing for that repository class.

and what is the good unit testing tool?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with testing your decorators at the moment? Their tests should be no different that tests of other classes. Show us some example code/give more context.

Answer (score 2):

When testing decorators (or proxies) you typically want to test the interaction rather than the state. For instance, for a cache you want to make sure the first call results in a call on the service behind while the second call does not.

I would recommend using a mocking framework since they are typically very good at testing interaction. There are [plenty of choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use).